# How to select all models with underscore in a field

Tags: mysql, laravel, replace, eloquent

This problem is giving me a hard time:

Whe I was learning to use a parsing tool, I added a large amount of records with uderscore (this --> _ ) in name, instead of space.

Now I wish to replace the underscores with spaces.
However, when I run this query:

```
$changethis = "_";
$object = Entity::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $changethis . '%')->limit(300)->get();
```

I get all records, even these without an underscore in the `name` field.

Any suggestions?

Thx

Comment: can you clarify a bit if you are looking to modify the schema table names and or columns, or more of a textual source code Find and Replace, or something else (if no one answers you who understands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIKE` has an option called `ESCAPE`.  The [default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) is a backslash, but you can change it:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%\_%'
```

or:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%$_%' ESCAPE '$'
```

Comment: the first one worked in my case. The other one gave me blank screen. No entry in error log. 

Thank you!